# Spring RestTemplate not able handle pound £ sign

Tags: json, spring-boot, resttemplate

My api is calling a third party web service which returns a String as below:

```
{
"message": "You have £100 in your account"
}
```

When I log the response in my application, the response is logged as below:

```
{
"message": "You have Â£100 in your account"
}
```

I used postman to check the response of the third party and it is sending the correct response. So, somehow my restTemplate is not able to handle this correctly. I went through some posts and added the `StringHttpMessageConverter` with `Charset.UTF_8` but that didnt work either.
`

Update:

Below is a code snippet:

```
public <T, S> ResponseEntity<S> send(HttpMethod method,
                                        HttpHeaders headers,
                                        T requestBody,
                                        URI uri,
                                        Class<S> responseClass)
        throws IOException {

    HttpEntity<T> httpEntity =
            new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    log.info("Calling {} {} {}", method.toString(), uri.toString(), headers.toString());
    log.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody));

    try {
        ResponseEntity<S> responseEntity =
                restTemplate
                        .exchange(uri,
                                method,
                                httpEntity,
                                responseClass);

        return responseEntity;

    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException statusCodeException) {
        log.info("-------------- " + statusCodeException.getResponseBodyAsString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Use Charset.UTF_16

Comment: You have a character encoding issue. It's hard to tell from your short description where the problem is - it could be anywhere in your code that deals with this data. It might even be possible that there's really no problem at all in your app itself, but that the tool you use to look at your logging uses the wrong character encoding.

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Can u pls take a look now.

Comment: @Antoniossss tried it. Doesnt work.

Comment: @Jesper Can you pls take a look now?

Answer (score 0):

add following to your application configuration

```
 http:
    encoding:
      force-request: true
      force-response: true
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
```