# Pound (£) sign in request parameters resolves with invalid characters

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, character-encoding, spring-restcontroller

I'm working on a Spring boot app with a rest controller endpoint and one of the request parameters accepting a price of an item, which contains the pound currency sign in the value. When reading the parameters it shows up with an invalid (or accent) character. Example below:

```
@RestController
public class Prices {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/prices", method = POST)
  public ResponseEntity createPrice(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters)
      throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    
    // Application logic

    String price = parameters.get("price");  => here the value is Â£100
    
    // Application logic continues    
  }
}
```

input given above is `£100` but the value in code is `Â£100`. I'm trying to get rid of that invalid character, tried below options but didn't work.

1. `StringUtils.stripAccent()` from commonslang3 - this replaced the Â to A
2. Added spring boot HTTP encoding properties as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/58096364/2727873

Comment: `Â£` (byte sequence `0xC2`,`0xA3`) is UTF-8 encoded _Pound Sign_ `£` (unicode `U+00A3`).

Comment: How you are testing it? I was testing from PostMan app and I recieved the value as I sent. So, please be sure the app or service where you are calling your endpoint uses charset=UTF-8

Comment: I was also trying it from the postman, but my request content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. this might have something to do with that symbol. Anyway, I've resolved this by reading the bytes from the parameter as ISO-8859-1 and converting back to a string again.